# For loops to line up attributes with corresponding value in python

Tags: python, loops

there are two list sample_attr and sample_val that store the position of column and the value of each column. the original data say row 1 (1:100 3:250 8:50 12:40,...531:300). there are 216 samples, each sample has 531 attributes. I first split the attribute and its value, fore example: sample_attr[0]->[1,3,8,12,...531], sample_val[0]->[100,250,50,40,...300]. each list of sample_attr stores attribute position(column 1, column 3..column 531) and each list of sample_val stores the value at corresponding attribute position. I want to do the for loops below, but it does not work to line up the attribute value in corresponding attribute position: it show error in line "for sample1 in sample_attr and sample2 in sample_val:". how I can line up the values with their corresponding attribute (column) position?

```
# adjust dimension

for sample1 in sample_attr and sample2 in sample_val:
    attr = [0]*maxdim
    s=0
    for i in sample1:
        attr[i-1] = sample2[s]
        s=s+1
    x.append(attr)
```

```
#the whole code below:

  with fileinput.input(files=('C:/Users/Documents/dataset.txt')) as f:
        for line in f:
            datalist.append(line.split())
        for exe in datalist:
            exe_attr = []
            exe_val=[]
            for i in range(0, len(exe)):
                exe_attr.append(int(exe[i].split(':', 1)[0]))
                exe_val.append(int(exe[i].split(':', 1)[1]))

                sample_attr.append(exe_attr)
                sample_val.append(exe_val)
        maxdim = 0
        for sample in sample_attr:
            if maxdim < sample[-1]:
                maxdim = sample[-1]
        maxdim = maxdim + 1
        x = []

        # adjust dimensiona not consistent
        for sample1 in sample_attr and sample2 in sample_val:
            attr = [0]*maxdim
            s=0
            for i in sample1:
                attr[i-1] = sample2[s]
                s=s+1
            x.append(attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not entirely sure how you expected this to work:

```
for sample1 in sample_attr and sample2 in sample_val:
```

because you supply a Boolean expression where you're expected to give an iterable.  I *think* what you wanted is more like

```
for sample1, sample2 in zip(sample_attr, sample_val):
```

However, you might be better off keeping this is a more "natural" data structure.  The `pandas` package is built specifically for working with data frames; check out the available documentation and tutorials, not to mention the thousands of examples here on Stack Overflow.  I strongly suspect that you can back up one step and read yoru data directly into a data frame.